# How do I build a .lib file containing Fortran functions, for use in a C program for Windows?

Tags: c, windows, fortran, static-libraries

I am trying to build a .lib file from Fortran subroutines. I know how to do a standard compilation like so:

My fortran files: mysub1.f90 and mysub2.f90

```
subroutine mysub1() bind (C, name="mysub1")
    print *, "Hello from mysub1"
end subroutine
```

and

```
subroutine mysub2() bind (C, name="mysub2")
    print *, "Hello from mysub2"
end subroutine
```

My header file: mysubs.h

```
#ifndef __MYSUBS_H__
#define __MYSUBS_H__

void mysub1();
void mysub2();

#endif
```

My main file: main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mysubs.h"

int main() {
    mysub1();
    mysub2();
    return 0;
}
```

My makefile:

```
CC=icx.exe
FC=ifort.exe

test.exe:
    $(FC) /c mysub1.f90
    $(FC) /c mysub2.f90
    $(CC) /c main.c
    $(CC) /o test.exe main.obj mysub1.obj mysub2.obj
```

How would I modify my makefile to build a .lib file containing mysub1() and mysub2(), and then statically link it when preparing test.exe?

Comment: I believe there is a librarian that would typically be used to combine the object files into a library.  I'm not sure what the typical incantation for that is, maybe you can find an example somewhere?